# Does denied reported speech take the subjunctive?

Tags: méxico, subjuntivo

If I say (in Mexican Spanish) that I did *not* say X, where X is information (rather than a command), does X take the subjunctive?

Regarding this question, Benjamin & Butt (5th ed.) seem to contradict themselves in section 16.7 with these two examples:

> Yo no he dicho que seas histérica.
> I never said you were a hysteric.
>
> No he dicho que venía.
> I didn't say that I was coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can take the subjunctive in the past form...

> Yo no he dicho que fueras histérica

Otherwise, your sentence sounds like this in English

> I have not said that you be hysterical.

Subjunctive in the sense that, the correct way to say this would be

> I have not said that you should be hysterical.

Just because you are using a negative in the sentence does not mean you need subjunctive.

Anyway, your sentence is not subjunctive..

If you negate X, then you can used the **imperative** (not subjunctive mood)

> Yo he dicho que no seas histérica.
>
> I have said for you not to be hysterical.

Comment: Thanks.  And I apologize for using B&B's rather confusing example.  Anyway, your "Just because ..." sentence is the answer that I was looking for.  I'll take it, although I felt obliged to report my own experience in class today.

Answer (score 0):

I confess that the examples from Butt & Benjamin are somewhat
confusing.  Sorry about that.  Anyway, I asked my native Mexican
Spanish teacher the following question today in class:

> Dado
>
> "Insistí en que eras un *bastante* buen estudiante.  No insistí en
>      que eras/fueras un *muy* buen estudiante."
>
> o
>
> "Te dije que eras un *bastante* buen estudiante.  No te dije que
>      eras/fueras un *muy* buen estudiante."
>
> ¿Deberia usar "eras" o "fueras"?

His answer was a definite "eras".  Based on this, I would say:

> "No dije que X" takes the same mode as "Dije que X".
>
> "No insistí en que X" takes the same mode as "Insistí en que X".

(And, of course, this mode can be either indicative or subjunctive,
depending on whether X is declared or commanded.)